# using several different functions

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

For my assignment, my program needs to ask the user which of the five functions he wants to execute. The five functions include:

1. Summation of a number
2. Factorial of a number
3. Fibonacci value of the nth term.
4. gcd of two numbers
5. a to the power of b.

The user will be prompted repeatedly until he wishes to exit. All my functions work fine. However, i think i messed up on one of the loops because once i enter which function i want to execute and enter a value, it keeps displaying the answer in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// function to find summation of a number
int summation(int k) {
  int i;

  for(i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
    k = i + (i-1);
  }
  return k;
}

// function to find the factorail of a number
int factorial(int num) {
  int i;

  for(i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    num = num * i;
  }
  return num;
}

// dunxtion to find the fibonacci of the nth term
int fibonacci(int n){
  int i, t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm;

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if(i == 1) {
        printf("%d, ", t1);
        continue;
    }
    if(i == 2) {
        printf("%d, ", t2);
        continue;
    }
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = nextTerm;
    printf("%d, ", nextTerm);
  }
  return nextTerm;
}

// function to find the gcd of two numbers
int gcd(int n, int m) {
  int i, gcd;

  for(i=1; i <= n && i <= m; i++) {
    // Checks if i is a factor of both integers
    if(n % i == 0 && m % i == 0)
        gcd = i;
  }
  return gcd;
}

// function to find value of n to the power of m
int power(int n, int m) {
  return pow(n, m);
}

int main(void) {;
  int option ,n, m;

//Asks user for what they want to find
  printf("If you would like to find the summation of a number, enter 1 \n");
  printf("If you would like to find the factorial of a number, enter 2 \n");
  printf("If you would like to find the fibonacci sequence of a number, enter 3 \n");
  printf("If you would like to find the gcd of two numbers, enter 4 \n");
  printf("If you would like to find the power of a number a to b, enter 5 \n");
  printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n");
  scanf("%d", &option);

// Enables the program to prompt the user until they wish to exit
  while(option != 0) {  
    switch(option) { //If user wishes to find the summation
        case 1: if(option == 1) {   
                    printf("Enter a number: ");
                    scanf("%d", &n);
                    while(n > 0) {
                        if(n < 1) { //message displayed if an invalid value is entered
                            printf("invalid value");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("Summation of %d is %d", n, summation(n));
                        }
                    }
                }
        case 2: if(option == 2) { //if user wishes to find factorial of a number
                    printf("Enter a number: ");
                    scanf("%d", &n);
                    while(n >= 0) {//message displayed if an invalid value is entered
                        if(n < 0) {
                            printf("invalid value");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("factorial of %d is %d", n, factorial(n));
                        }
                    }
                }
        case 3: if(option == 3) { //if user wishes to find the fibonacci value of the nth term
                    printf("Enter a number: ");
                    scanf("%d", &n);
                    while(n >= 0) {//message displayed if an invalid value is entered
                        if(n < 0) {
                            printf("invalid value");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("fibonacci of %d is %d", n, fibonacci(n));
                        }
                    }
                }
        case 4: if(option == 4) { 
                    printf("Enter a number: ");
                    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
                    while(n >= 0 && m >= 0) {
                        if(n < 0 || m < 0) {//message displayed if an invalid value is entered
                            printf("invalid value");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("GCD of %d and %d is %d", n, m, gcd(n, m));
                        }
                    }
                }
        case 5: if(option == 5) {
                    printf("Enter a number: ");
                    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
                    while(n >= 0 && m >= 0) {
                        if(n <= 0 || m < 0) {
                            printf("invalid value");
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("%d to the power of %d is %d", n, m, power(n, m));
                        }
                    }
                }
        default: if(option == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
}
```

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `if(option == 1)` and alike.. D.R.Y.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: I recommend you [find a good beginners book to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, C has unstructured `switch` statement.

You need to add a `break;` statement after each of your `case` body to *limit* the execution for a particular case to the body mentioned under that `case`.

Otherwise, by default, (with the absence of a `break` statement) all the `case` statements works in **fall-through** manner. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

---

That said, regarding the repeated execution of a single function, there's a serious flaw in most (if not all) of the the logic. For example, let's take this

```
   while(n > 0) {
     if(n < 1) { //message displayed if an invalid value is entered
         printf("invalid value");
     }
     else {
         printf("Summation of %d is %d", n, summation(n));
     }
   }
```

here, you're replying on `n` becoming 0 at some point to break out of the loop, but you did not modify `n`, at all.

To elaborate, C uses pass-by-value for argument passing, so for the call, `summation(n)`, inside the function, whatever change you make to the parameter receiving the value of `n`, is not reflected in the caller, and thus, the `n` in the caller remains unchanged.

Comment: Yeah i completely forgot about the break statements. But even after adding them in, it still has the same problem.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed you mean it still executes _all_ the functions?

Comment: All the functions are not executed. Let's say I enter 2 for variable "option" which finds the factorial of a an entered number. The function is executed properly. The only problem is that it keeps displaying the answer constantly in an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahh.. I see, i get it now..wait for an update to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `break` statement at the end of every case 
like:

```
 case 1: if(option == 1) { 
                printf("Enter a number: ");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                while(n > 0) {
                    if(n < 1) { //message displayed if an invalid value is entered
                        printf("invalid value");
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Summation of %d is %d", n, summation(n));
                    }
                }
            } 
break;
```

As the control will fall down to next case if no break statement is present.